# NestJS: How to catch the error throw from Observable by useFilter?

Tags: nestjs

I would like to catch all Error throw from `readCreationMessage` in `TeamsController`, as you can see in below code snippet, `this.apiCallerService.post` is an Observable and I tried to catch the error from `ApiCallerService`. But once `readCreationMessage` throw error (which I want `NoExceptionFilter` could catch), the application crashes.

How can I catch the exception by using @UseFilters(new NoExceptionFilter())?

TeamsController:

```
@Controller()
@UseFilters(new NoExceptionFilter())
@Catch()
export class TeamsController {
    constructor(
        private apiCallerService: ApiCallerService
    ) {}

    // A dictionary to save retry message and retry count
    retries = {};

    @MessagePattern(TEAM_CREATION)
    readCreationMessage(@Payload() message: IncomingKafkaMessage<CloudEvent>) {
        
        const payload = {
            name: data.name,
        };

        this.apiCallerService
            .post(TEST_ENDPOINTS.TEAM_CREATION, payload)
            .pipe(
                catchError((err) => {
                    throw new HttpException(
                        { status: HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, error: 'wfff323232ff' },
                        403,
                    );
                    
                }),
                map((res) => {
                    Logger.log('subscribe map');
                }),
            )
            .subscribe((err) => {
                Logger.log('subscribe error');
                throw new Error();
            });
}
```

ApiCallerService:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiCallerService {
    constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService,
        private configService: ConfigService,
    ) {}

    private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:4001';

    post(path: string, data: any): Observable<AxiosResponse> {
        const response = this.httpService
            .post(`${this.baseUrl}${path}`, data,)
            .pipe(
                catchError((e) => {
                    Logger.log('Exception', e);
                    of('err', e);
                    return throwError(() => new Error(e));
                    
                }),
            );

        return response;
    }
    }
```

NoExceptionFilter:

```
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BaseRpcExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Catch()
export class NoExceptionFilter implements BaseRpcExceptionFilter {
    handleUnknownError(exception: any, status: string): Observable<never> {
        // Logger.info("NoExceptionFilter handleUnknownError");
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    isError(exception: any): exception is Error {
        // Logger.info("NoExceptionFilter isError");
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
        // Logger.info("NoExceptionFilter isError");
        console.log('Error caught', exception, host, host.getArgs()[0]);
        throw 'Error occurred during message catch';
        //return throwError(exception.getError());
    }
}
```

Comment: Having the same issue, did you found any solution or workaround? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook the NodeJs process and add a callback handler in the constructor of your ExceptionFilter to catch and process unhandled rejection errors from async functions:

```js
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BaseRpcExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Catch()
export class NoExceptionFilter implements BaseRpcExceptionFilter {

    constructor() {
        // catch unhandled errors in async calls
        process.on('uncaughtException', (err: Error) => {
          Logger.error(
            ` Uncaught Exception Error: ${err.message}\n${err.stack}`,
            'AllExceptionsFilter',
          );
        });
        process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason: any, promise: Promise<any>) => {
          // NOTE: if you receive this error message, most likely there was an error within an
          // unresolved Promise or Observable without .catch() function. Please implement a proper .catch() function!

          Logger.error(
            ` Unhandled Rejection Error: ${reason}\n${reason.stack}`,
            'AllExceptionsFilter',
          );
        });
    }

    handleUnknownError(exception: any, status: string): Observable<never> {
        // Logger.info("NoExceptionFilter handleUnknownError");
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    isError(exception: any): exception is Error {
        // Logger.info("NoExceptionFilter isError");
        throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    }
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
        // Logger.info("NoExceptionFilter isError");
        console.log('Error caught', exception, host, host.getArgs()[0]);
        throw 'Error occurred during message catch';
        //return throwError(exception.getError());
    }
}
```